# Repeat element on every page of an RDLC outside of header/footer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting, rdlc

In VS2010 I have a report, with a table of data that can cause the report to span multiple pages.

Also on this report I have a rectangle that has some contact information for the company the report is for, that I need it to repeat on every page, to the side of the previous table.  However this rectangle is not, and cannot be in the header or footer.  Is there a way to make an element of a report repeat on every page?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there isn't. You'll have to mimic this by splitting your report into pieces and forcing page breaks after which you display the header again. You can use the `List` component to do this and group your data to a fixed row height to break to a next page.